# Cant access site using webclient method..?

Tags: c#

I am making a desktop yellowpage application. I can access all countries yellowpage site but not australian site. I dont know why?

Here is the code

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebClient wb = new WebClient();
        wb.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US)");
        string html = wb.DownloadString("http://www.yellowpages.com.au");
        Console.WriteLine(html);
    }
}
```

For all other site I get html of the website for australian site I get null. i even tried httpwebrequest also.

Here is the yellowpage australian site: http://www.yellowpages.com.au

Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea why. What errors/exceptions are you getting?

Comment: I didnt goy any errors or exceptions

Comment: If you post code, post your real code, not something that won't even compile.

Comment: I think above code can be compiled.

Comment: And now that it works, please note the copyright notice near the end of that html string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like that website will only send over gzip'ed data.  Try switching to HttpWebRequest and using auto decompression:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.yellowpages.com.au");
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @bkaid's correct (and upvoted) answer, you can use your own class inherited from `WebClient` to uncompress/handle gzip compressed html:

```
public class GZipWebClient : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | 
                                         DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        return request;
    }
}
```

Having done this, the following works just fine:

```
WebClient wb = new GZipWebClient();
string html = wb.DownloadString("http://www.yellowpages.com.au");
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

When I view the transfer from that website in Wireshark, it says it's a malformed HTTP packet. It says it uses [chunked transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding), then says the following chunk has 0 bytes and then sends the code of the website. That's why `WebClient` returns an empty string (not `null`). And I think it's correct behavior.

It seems browsers ignore this error and so they can display the page properly.

**EDIT:**

As bkaid pointed out, the server seems to handle send correct gziped response. The following code works for me:

```
WebClient wb = new WebClient();
wb.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
string html;
using (var webStream = wb.OpenRead("http://www.yellowpages.com.au"))
using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(webStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(gzipStream))
    html = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: yeah.. I saw the chunked transfer and it says content length 0 when I viewed the web response through debugging mode in visual studio. It says content length -1 and it doesnt show content encoding  .. Hence I didnt understand what is happening there.. Anyway thank you it worked.